# Performance tuning of HIVE tables using index - works and issues?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-partitioning

I have an `external` hive table `abc` with 3 columns -

```
c1 string,
c2 int, 
c3 string
```

I did create a `COMPACT index` on the column `c1` as part of `create index` statement with deferred rebuild.

Now, I do an `alter index on abc with rebuild`; so my index table gets loaded with offsets and data.

Here are my queries:

1) should I query against the base table `abc` to see the performance improvement?

2) should I query against the new index table?

3) is this the only property to set - `set hive.optimize.index.filter=true`?

In spite of indexing the column `c1`, when I query against table `abc` with filter conditions on column `c1`, I do not see any performance improvement; even the `explain` plan does not show a case of using index.

What is the issue? can someone guide me, thanks.